# Getting response from CefSharp Javascript

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I use CefSharp to browse a website and get profile names.
So I execute javascript and get the names and want to get an response with the names.

I tried multiple codes for a couple of hours but it wont work and I can't get any data.

```
   private async void TEST()
    {
         var script = @"(function(){return 'HALLOOOO'})";
        // JavascriptResponse response = await browser.EvaluateScriptAsync(script);

        var result = await browser.GetMainFrame().EvaluateScriptAsync(script)
        .ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            var result1 = t.Result;
            return (string)result1.ToString();
        });
        richTextBox1.Text = result;
    }

 private void button3_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {


        TEST();
        
    }
```

I tested it with a return string but, what I get in the richtextbox is following:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1ueP.png)

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: You need to execute the function

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add this, but I execute the function with a button click.

Comment: A self executing JavaScript function requires an additional set of open and close braces to execute. Answer below is correct.

Comment: Further review you should use either ContinueWith or await. Using ContinueWith and passing in the the UI taskscheduler https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.fromcurrentsynchronizationcontext?view=netcore-3.1#System_Threading_Tasks_TaskScheduler_FromCurrentSynchronizationContext is an easy way to update the UI.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith?view=netcore-3.1#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_ContinueWith_System_Action_System_Threading_Tasks_Task__System_Threading_Tasks_TaskScheduler_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to execute the function , not just to declare it:

```
     var script = @"(function(){return 'HALLOOOO'})();";
```

Comment: Where is actually the data? In Message or Result? Because I changed it like u did and tried it on chrome console and there it worked.